# Laravel 5.1 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isSuperAdmin()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

So I'm trying to understand user authorization in Laravel 5.1.

Based on the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#defining-abilities) I've set up the AuthServiceProvider boot method as follows:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    parent::registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('view-dashboard', function ($user, $post) {        
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    });

    $gate->before(function ($user, $ability) {
        if($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }
    });   
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
    if (Gate::denies('view-dashboard')) {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    return view('admin.home');
```

When I'm not logged in I get the auth.login view. However, once I log in I get the following error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2025: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isSuperAdmin()

First, since I took those lines straight out of the docs, I'm not sure why I would get that error. Any ideas?

Second, the docs don't seem to explain how to go about designating a given user as a Super Admin, or how to give a user specific abilities (such as the "view-dashboard" ability in my example). How do I do this?

UPDATE: Here is my user model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your model **User** you didn't defined the method **isSuperAdmin**

```
public function isSuperAdmin()
{
    // your logic here
    return true; // or false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check AuthServiceProvider for the line:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

by default my file have:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
```

after replace all work fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Super Admin middlewhere may not be defined.

Within `app/Http/Kernel.php` you will see a directive named `routeMiddleware`. Add the following line within the array.

`'superadmin'    => 'App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware'`

You also didn't supply your `User` model. Please can you double check that the `User` model implements at least the following interfaces and traits.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, there is no routeMiddleware in my config/app.php. I did find $routeMiddleware in app\Http\Kernel.php. 

To that I added         'superadmin'    => \App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware::class

But it still throws the same error

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know

Comment: Yes, my user model implements all of those (I've updated my question to include the user model)

Comment: I've added 'superadmin'    => 'App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware' to $routeMiddleware in Kernel.php file, but I still get the same error. FYI, the route is /admin not /superadmin Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Also, FYI, there is no SuperAdmin.php in the App\Http\Middleware folder. If I need this file, where do I find what should go in it?